# Network_Storage.storageTierLevel should not be a string type

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Document is wrong:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage

Refer to below REST call and response

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/13923041/getObject.json?objectMask=mask[id,storageTierLevel]

```
{
    "id": 13923041,
    "storageTierLevel":
    {
        "allowCancellationFlag": 1,
        "associatedBillingItemId": "123709989",
        "cancellationDate": null,
        "categoryCode": "storage_tier_level",
        "createDate": "2016-08-31T02:09:15-07:00",
        "cycleStartDate": "2016-11-01T02:18:19-07:00",
        "description": "0.25 IOPS per GB",
        "id": 123709993,
        "laborFee": "0",
        "laborFeeTaxRate": "0",
        "lastBillDate": "2016-11-01T02:18:19-07:00",
        "modifyDate": "2016-11-01T02:18:19-07:00",
        "nextBillDate": "2016-12-01T00:00:00-06:00",
        "oneTimeFee": "0",
        "oneTimeFeeTaxRate": "0",
        "orderItemId": 149747285,
        "parentId": 123709989,
        "recurringFee": "0",
        "recurringFeeTaxRate": "0",
        "recurringMonths": 1,
        "serviceProviderId": 1,
        "setupFee": "0",
        "setupFeeTaxRate": "0"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks we will report it.

Comment: Is this type a Billing_Item? I can have my datatype fixed before your metadata or document fixed.

Comment: I added an answer please see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with documentation, the issue is related to the objectMask. Currently it is returning a billingItem item which is wrong.

if you execute this request:

```
GET https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/13923041/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,storageTierLevel,billingItem[children]]
```

you will notice that one of the children of the billingItem has the same value displayed on "storageTierLevel" property.

I have no idea when they will fix it.

meanwhile you can use this request:

```
GET https://$USERNAME:$APIKEYapi.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/13923041/getObject?objectMask=storageTierLevel;id
```

Regards

Comment: this REST call returns: READHEAVY_TIER or LOW_INTENSITY_TIER, but from current storageTierLevel.description, it is '0.25 IOPS per GB', is there a mapping between the name and number(eg.0.25), I eventually needs this number to find corresponding price, is there any other way to get this number? (python client splits this storageTierLevel.description with whitespace, and take [0] as the tier number)

Comment: yep there is a mapping LOW_INTENSITY_TIER ->0.25 IOPS
READHEAVY_TIER -> 2 IOPS
WRITEHEAVY_TIER -> 4 IOPS

Comment: the another way to get the IOPS is in the billing item children GET https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/13923041/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,storageTierLevel,billingItem[children]]  and look for the item which description contains IOPS

Comment: Thank you! I will use this mapping.

Comment: One more question, what is the name for tier = 10 IOPS per GB?

Comment: it is "storageTierLevel" = "10_IOPS_PER_GB"